# Add Click Event Listener for any control in entire solution

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, addeventlistener

Is there a way to add a Click Event Listener to any Button?

I want to fire a method when any button is clicked from any form in the solution.

I know i can add an event listener for each button on its own but it will be quite redundant in my case.

Thanks

Comment: Why not make a method and call that method in each button?

Comment: Easy. Create a base form and inherit all other forms from this baseform. In the base form you can loop thru all buttons and add an event handler.

Comment: Derive a class from Button and add the listener to it, use that button instead of the standard one.

Comment: @Crowcoder, thanks for the input. But my project is almost done and i dont want to change every button created.

Comment: @FreekW. i know that works. thanks though

Comment: @GuidoG im not sure if thats optimal in my case. I will have to loop through every form or OpenForms and set the event handler for every control.

Maybe a simple loop on Each form load will save me some time and i set the handler for all the buttons. Not optimal though.

Crowcoder's way is probably the best just not in my case.

thanks everyone

Comment: No, you only have to do this on your baseform where you inherited all other forms from. Unless you did not created a baseform off course...

Comment: Created a base form "form1" that inherits Form

and i created another form "form2" that inherits "form1". @GuidoG

Comment: you should have started your project with creating a base form that inherits from Form. Than all other forms in your project should have been inherited from that baseform. If you have this setup, than things like what you need now are very simple to do on your baseform. Do you have such a setup ?

Comment: In the Show event for example of the baseform, you can loop through all controls of type Button and couple it to one event on the baseform. This loop is only needed once, on the baseform. That is how I do this. It should see all buttons created by the child form also

Comment: @GuidoG. Your way works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: no problem, glad I could help