# C# WinForms MDI form jumps to the back when I disable the form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

Whenever I do `this.Enabled = false` the MDI child form jumps to the back of all the other forms.

The reason I disable the form is because I am performing a search, and the user must wait a moment for the response.

How do I change this behaviour?

I tried `Activate()` and `BringToFront()` immediately following it. It brings the form to the front, but does not give it focus.

Comment: this is not a good way to do that. Why not create a modal form with a progressbar or any other kind of animation, and close it when the search is done. You could even add a Cancel button then

Comment: That might be the better way to go...

Comment: ... but I am not entirely sure how to implement this. Solution 1. Since this is an MDI form, using e.g. `progressBarForm.ShowDialog(this)` will also prevent me from interacting with any of the other MDI child forms. Solution 2. Suppose instead I want a picture on a transparent panel drawn on the form, which is possible, I want to prevent the user from interacting with the controls behind this panel. I do not know of a method other than `Enabled = false` to do this. Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 2):

So you want one MDI Child form to be `disabled` (but not hidden) while it is doing a search or some lengthy operation. And it should still be available.
And you also want all other MDI Child forms to stay available.

Here is one way of doing this:

- put all controls on this MDI Child form on a panel that is
  docked=filled.
- simply put this panel.Enabled = false during the search and leave the form itself untouched.

This way your form is still enabled, but all controls are not accesable until your search is done. And all other forms also still available.

Comment: I can see how this would work, but we have way over 50 forms on this project. I was hoping for a quick solution.

Comment: Surely you have created a BaseForm and all your other 50 forms are inherited from that base form. Just implement this on your baseform and done

Comment: Its the same principle as in this question. the answer is i the comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813972/add-click-event-listener-for-any-control-in-entire-solution

Comment: sorry to hear that, allthough even my legacy projects already have this. OOP was there in the beginning of dotnet so there was no excuse back then to not having done this. But that does not helps you now, sorry